# How to load image from network path via php

Tags: php, html, image, networking, path

I am trying to load an image from a network path into my php file. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $image_src="//SERVER/2 MESHES/80 - RailClone Lib/Geländer/thumbnails/Geländer 2.jpg";
    echo '<img src='.$image_src.' alt="No Image">';
?>
```

The image is not loaded --- I alwas see No Image. 
What do I have to do to access the file on the network server? I am using firefox.
Thanks for helping!

Addition: I changed the image Source to

```
$image_src="file://S:/2 MESHES/80 - RailClone Lib/Geländer/thumbnails/Geländer 2.jpg";

echo "<img src='".$image_src."' alt='No Image'>";
```

Now I can copy the code out of the sourcecode and it opens in the browser, but the php file does not load the file.

The generated sourcecode looks like this:

```
<img src='file://S:/2 MESHES/80 - RailClone Lib/Geländer/thumbnails/Geländer 2.jpg' alt='No Image'>
```

Comment: There is an error with your PHP which I corrected in my answer. But the file you're trying to access is not accessible via `HTTP`. Local servers can be accessed using windows explorer to get files by default. But they need to be reconfigured in order to give access to file through `HTTP` request. What you need to do is to contact the admin of your network ans ask him to give access.

Comment: I am working with xampp

Answer (score 0):

Try thins.

Change this,

```
echo '<img src='.$image_src.' alt="No Image">';
```

To this,

```
echo "<img src=".$image_src." alt='No Image'>";
```

Comment: Makes no big difference.
Changed code to:

`echo "<img src='".$image_src."' alt='No Image'>";`

output is: 
`<img src='//SERVER/2 MESHES/80 - RailClone Lib/Geländer/thumbnails/Geländer 2.jpg' alt='No Image'>`

Again gives me No image...

Comment: Dow you server give access to files through web browsers ? not all local server are configured to give access via a web client.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the client that access the generated HTML page have access to this image. In fact the image on the HTML img tag is not retrieve by PHP but by your browser following the URL you provided in the attribute src. So if the browser can't access the URL, the image won't be loaded.

Comment: How do I manage to check? Is there no way to access network files outside my localhost?

Comment: To check go on your browser's developer tools (or Firebug...) and on the network tab you should see a request that corresponds to your browser retrieving the image. If the status code is 404, the server might not be accessible.

Concerning the network files, we can't really help you without knowing where the network configuration. is it hosted on the same machine, on a VM, on another server ? Which ports of these machines are open ... ?

Answer (score 0):

USE  `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to get the correct path of the server to get the Image.

*corrected*

> `echo "<img src=".$image_src." alt='No Image'>";`

```
<?php

 $image_src="//SERVER/2 MESHES/80 - RailClone Lib/Geländer/thumbnails/Geländer 2.jpg";
    echo "<img src=".$image_src." alt='No Image'>";

?>
```