# PHP: Display an image from a password protected network storage

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to display this image from a network storage device (Buffalo) which is password protected. How do I do that please? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="\\192.168.1.10\IMG\ANAFISHER.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could access it through php only. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051796/how-to-load-image-from-network-path-via-php

Comment: Thank you for your response and for sending the link. I tried it but it won't work because the network storage we have has a password. There needs to be password in the lines of code.